# Fatal error message after installng drupal

Tags: bootstrapping

I get this error message when uploading the site on the server. I really need help.

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/mydomain/public_html/includes/drupal/includes/database/select.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear') in /home/mydomain/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 3160

Comment: That's not an FTP error but a php error, so it should not occur during uploading. Please make sure all files are in place before trying to run them. (Can't run a half installed Windows system either).

Answer (score 1):

This error say that can not  the specified file '/home/mydomain/public_html/includes/drupal/includes/database/select.inc' , It may happened by 2 reason , one permission and another reason ( with more probability ) The file not exist, please make sure that the file exist or have permission .